# Google Cloud Storage - Control bot access to public files. Limit class b operations

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I know that once you made an object public in GCS it can be reached from anywhere. Is there any workaround that could be applied to difficult or avoid continuous bot access to it that could lead to huge expenses?

If there is not, is there a way to limit the number of class A/B operations in order to avoid being continuously targeted by a bot?

Best,

Kike

Answer (score 0):

According to the oficial documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public):

> When an object is shared publicly, any user with knowledge of the
>   object URI can access the object for as long as the object is public.

[Google Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/) delivers defense against DDos attacks by using Google's gclobal infrastructure and security system.

However IP deny list/allow list for HTTP(S) Load Balancing is not supported for Cloud Storage backends [link](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-concepts#restrictions). Therefore you can not use Google Cloud Armor to limit the number of requests to public Google Cloud Storage buckets.